# How can child processes of mongo can be killed?

Tags: linux, mongodb, cpu-usage

I have following mongo process tree in LINUX server.

```
mongod(1168)─┬─{mongod}(1366)
        ├─{mongod}(1367)
        ├─{mongod}(1370)
        ├─{mongod}(1376)
        ├─{mongod}(1378)
        ├─{mongod}(1380)
        ├─{mongod}(1381)
        ├─{mongod}(1382)
        ├─{mongod}(1383)
        ├─{mongod}(1412)
        ├─{mongod}(1413)
        ├─{mongod}(1415)
        ├─{mongod}(1417)
        ├─{mongod}(1418)
        ├─{mongod}(1420)
        ├─{mongod}(1421)
        ├─{mongod}(1422)
        ├─{mongod}(1430)
        ├─{mongod}(1435)
        ├─{mongod}(1605)
        ├─{mongod}(1607)
        ├─{mongod}(1736)
        ├─{mongod}(1737)
        ├─{mongod}(1924)
        └─{mongod}(1925)
```

I want to kill 1925 process, not parent (1168). Is there any possible ways to kill child processes only & free up the consume memory be zombie/dead processes of mongo.

This mongo processes keeps on increasing & consume CPU 100%.

Comment: I think you should try to identify why that child process is consuming CPU. Is there a bad query somewhere?

Comment: As per the earlier comment, it would be much better to identify what the issue is. If you have a recurring problem, killing or restarting processes is a disruptive (and temporary fix). You can use `db.currentOp()` to display running processes in the `mongo` shell and `db.killOp()` to request the operation terminate. You'd want to use this approach with caution and avoid killing any system threads. Alternatively, you could just restart your `mongod` service. What are your specific versions of MongoDB and O/S? Also, what sort of deployment do you have (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster)?